# What components are needed for a 20MHz square wave clock?

Tags: oscillator, clock, crystal, z80

I would like to create a 20Mhz clock that generates a square wave for the home-brew Z80 computer I' making. I already have several 20MHz crystal oscillators but am at a loss when it comes to circuit diagrams and other components needed. I have looked around but I haven't found any diagrams with all of the details that I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your Z80 can run at 20MHz? The fastest version I am aware of was Z80H, which ran at 8MHz max.

Comment: The one I bought is in fact the 20MHz model

Comment: @jippie it goes up to 25 MHz; see the end of this page http://www.z80.info/z80brief.htm

Comment: @Cornelius I wasn't aware of those advances. Last time I checked the Z80 datasheets there was no such thing as SMD or QFP and I thought development was discontinued after the 8MHz version.

Comment: @jippie neither did I, but I found it in that link.

Comment: Frankly, I'd recommend just buying a 20 MHz clock oscillator. It will save space and be more reliable. eBay is your friend here - it took a few minutes to find 4 units for $7.00, free shipping.

Comment: OP said "I already have several 20MHz crystal oscillators".  Do you care to share any part numbers, @VivaDaylight3?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks for the input, but I don't live in the US like most people assume, and I can't find any of those on the UK Ebay site :/

Comment: @TimH Unfortunately there aren't any part numbers on the crystal, only the frequency (20.0MHz)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a 74 series IC ([7400](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf), [7404](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf), [7406](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls06.pdf) etc.), two capacitors and two resistors.

Here is one possible circuit for a square wave clock generator:

[image]

Source: [z80.info](http://www.z80.info/uexosc.htm) by [Thomas Scherrer](http://www.z80.info/). Also check his site for more Z80 related information.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a crystal oscillator (they usually come in a 4-pin can), you just have to apply power (and ground) to the oscillator, and it will produce a 20 MHz square wave, which can be fed directly into the Z80's clock input.

If you have a plain crystal (usually in a 2-pin can), the other answers show possible oscillator circuits.